# Custom loading indicator (spinner)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

I wanted to replace the default spinner which comes in when data is being loaded from the server with my custom image. I have 16 images for that.

Any idea how to replace that with custom loading indicator?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done using a UIImageView (you can create a custom UIView subclass for doing it if you like). The basic code is something like this:

```
UIImageView* animatedImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];

animatedImageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:    
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-01.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-02.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-03.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"spinner-04.png"], 
                            nil];

animatedImageView.animationDuration = 1.0;
animatedImageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;

[animatedImageView startAnimating];
```